# Apache Nifi Web Server keeps failing to start with Decryption exception

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a setup in which NiFi Web Server suddenly started failing to start when upgrading from `1.15.3` to `1.16.1` version. The following exception keeps occurring on the Apache NiFi Cluster:

```
2022-05-11 22:53:40,570 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... shutting down.
org.apache.nifi.encrypt.EncryptionException: Decryption Failed with Algorithm [PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL]
        at org.apache.nifi.encrypt.CipherPropertyEncryptor.decrypt(CipherPropertyEncryptor.java:78)
        at org.apache.nifi.fingerprint.FingerprintFactory.decrypt(FingerprintFactory.java:931)
        at org.apache.nifi.fingerprint.FingerprintFactory.getLoggableRepresentationOfSensitiveValue(FingerprintFactory.java:561)
        at org.apache.nifi.fingerprint.FingerprintFactory.addParameter(FingerprintFactory.java:330)
        at org.apache.nifi.fingerprint.FingerprintFactory.addParameterContext(FingerprintFactory.java:302)
        at org.apache.nifi.fingerprint.FingerprintFactory.addFlowControllerFingerprint(FingerprintFactory.java:210)
        at org.apache.nifi.fingerprint.FingerprintFactory.createFingerprint(FingerprintFactory.java:153)
        at org.apache.nifi.fingerprint.FingerprintFactory.createFingerprint(FingerprintFactory.java:127)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.inheritance.FlowFingerprintCheck.checkInheritability(FlowFingerprintCheck.java:45)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.XmlFlowSynchronizer.sync(XmlFlowSynchronizer.java:200)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.serialization.StandardFlowSynchronizer.sync(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:43)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.synchronize(FlowController.java:1524)
        at org.apache.nifi.persistence.StandardFlowConfigurationDAO.load(StandardFlowConfigurationDAO.java:104)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.loadFromBytes(StandardFlowService.java:815)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.load(StandardFlowService.java:457)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:1086)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:170)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:82)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:330)
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$BufferedGenericBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2168)
        at org.apache.nifi.encrypt.CipherPropertyEncryptor.decrypt(CipherPropertyEncryptor.java:74)
        ... 18 common frames omitted
```

relevant `nifi.properties`:

```
nifi.sensitive.props.key=<hidden>
nifi.sensitive.props.key.protected=
nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm=PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
nifi.sensitive.props.additional.keys=
```

I have already tried to tear it all down and re-install `1.15.3` with not any other changes, but the same issue still persists. Can someone please share any ideas if there are any on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is a late response, but answering anyways because someone else might benefit from it.

The error indicates that new NiFi version is not able to decrypt the flow.xml.gz that came from old NiFi version.

When a value is set for nifi.sensitive.props.key in nifi.properties, the specified key is used to encrypt sensitive properties in the flow (e.g. password fields in components).
i) If the key needs to change,
ii) or you forget the props key
iii) or hit an issue like above where new NiFi cannot decrypt flow.xml.gz, then the Encrypt-Config tool in the NiFi Toolkit can migrate the sensitive properties key and update the flow.xml.gz.

Specifically, Encrypt-Config:
Reads the existing flow.xml.gz and decrypts the sensitive values using the current key.

Encrypts all the sensitive values with a specified new key.

Updates the nifi.properties and flow.xml.gz files or creates new versions of them.

So to resolve your issue, we will need old flow.xml.gz, nifi.properties, bootstrap.conf and a new password (props key) to use.

The run the below command:

```
     $ ./nifi-toolkit-1.10.0/bin/encrypt-config.sh -f /path/to/oldNiFi_Conf/flow.xml.gz -g /path/to/newNiFi_Conf/flow.xml.gz -s new_password -n /path/to/oldNiFi_Conf/nifi.properties -o /path/to/newNiFi_Conf/nifi.properties -b /path/to/oldNiFi_Conf/bootstrap.conf -x
```

Then, put newNiFi_Conf/flow.xml.gz in the required NiFi work directory and set the nifi.sensitive.props.key to new_password used in the command and restart NiFi.

See [Encrypt-Config Tool usage here](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/toolkit-guide.html#encrypt_config_tool:%7E:text=to%20NiFiRegistryCommandGroup.-,Encrypt%2DConfig%20Tool,-The%20encrypt%2Dconfig).